# HTTPS connection with RDFLib

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, amazon-neptune, rdflib

I am using Python and the RDFLib library and I want to perform an HTTPS connection to a SPARQL endpoint such as Amazon Nepute (HTTPS is mandatory) and perform authentication. However, I cannot find in the documentation of RDFLib any descriptions, hints or examples concerning authentication methods different than Basic Authentication. Does RDFLib support other authentication approaches (such as JWT)?

Comment: HTTPS is not an authentication method so it is unclear what exactly you mean. For example, I can query any HTTPS exposed SPARQL endpoint without any issues, e.g. Wikidata or DBpedia

Comment: You are right, my question was really ill posed. I've edited it. Long story short, I would like to know the authentication method supported by RDFLib

Comment: Can you provide the code that you currently have written? It would help understand which features of RDFLib you're using to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `SPARQLStore`](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.plugins.stores.html#rdflib.plugins.stores.sparqlstore.SPARQLStore) states:

> The underlying SPARQLConnector uses the urllib library. Any extra kwargs passed to the SPARQLStore connector are passed to urllib when doing HTTP calls. I.e. you have full control of cookies/auth/headers.

So you could authenticate separately using urllib, retrieve the cookies/tokens received, and then pass them into RDFLib.